# JUnit testing error with ArrayQueue

Tags: java, junit

I'm currently doing a bit JUnit testing on an ArrayQueue with 5 simple methods(seek(), peek(), poll(), offer(item), iterator()).
The issue I am having is when I run this test...

```
@Test
public void testAddingToQueue() {       
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {     
        assertTrue("Queue should successfully add item " + i, queue.offer("v" + i));       
        assertFalse("Queue should not be empty after add", queue.isEmpty());
        assertEquals("Size should be " + i + " after " + i + " adds", i, queue.size());
   }
}
```

The error I get is...
Queue should not be empty after add

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Queue should not be empty after add at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91) at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43) at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:68) at ArrayQueueTest.testAddingToQueue(ArrayQueueTest.java:65)
```

I don't understand how the queue is empty as I'm adding a String to the queue in the `assertTrue` line... any help would be appreciated thanks.

Constructor

```
public ArrayQueue() {
    data = (E[]) new Object[INITIALCAPACITY];
}
```

Add method

```
public boolean offer(E item) {
    if (item == null)return false;
    else {
        ensureCapacity();
        data[back] = item;
        back = (back+1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayQueue` is not a standard Java class. I'm guessing that you have a bug in your implementation...

Comment: Based on your use of methods, I'm assuming you mean `ArrayBlockingQueue` ?

Comment: No ArrayQueue, a simple implementation I created myself.

Comment: In that case can we see the `offer` method? Also how do you construct/initialise the queue?

Comment: In the test method I just inialize it by... queue = new ArrayQueue<String>();

Comment: May we also see your `isEmpty()` method?

Comment: I don't have an isEmpty() method. I'm using the java.util.Collection isEmpty()... could this be my problem?

Comment: if you invoke, `java.util.collection.size()` what do you get?

Comment: Having trouble invoking it, how do you suggest I proceed?

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL: Are you extending `AbstractCollection`? If so, `isEmpty()` requires you to provide a working `size()` method. What does your `size()` method look like?

Comment: I'm extending AbstractQueue<E>.....

Comment: public int size () {
        return back-1 - front;     
    }

Comment: Hm, seems like a circular buffer. Those can be *very* tricky to get right - trust me I know. Any reason you are writing this by hand, rather than using an `ArrayDeque` ?

Comment: Just an assignment for Uni, we were given some instructions and I'm just following their guidelines...

Comment: Right, well then I would *really* check the `size()` method, before checking `isEmpty()`. Depending on the way you handle the boundary values and their initial values, `size()` might even return `-1` in some cases...

Comment: If you dont give us all your code we cannot help you. BTW: add the index variable to the assert which fails (same way you do it for offer). It is interesting to know if it is first or later iteration (Especially if "later" is after resize of backing array).

Comment: BTW: I dont think this is really "Junit" related - the title and the tags are rather missleading. You pretty much used JUnit correctly. And if you dont think so, replace it by if/println or just use a debugger.

Comment: @eckes: well, I guess if the OP gives us their code, everyone in their class has it too...

Comment: Just got it..the size method should be back - front, not back -1 - front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class extends `AbstractQueue`, which in turn extends `AbstractCollection`. If you have not provided your own `isEmpty()` implementation, then the default implementation looks like this:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}
```

I suspect that the issue lies in your `size()` implementation. You could try reversing the order of the last two JUnit tests in your code, so that `size()` is tested before `isEmpty()` to find out if (and for which index) it breaks.

In any case, the [Wikipedia page on circular buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) provides a lot of useful information and some implementation details for array-based queues like the one you are building.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `isEmpty()` method from the superclass, but you are not invoking the superclass `add()` method; the superclass is unaware that anything has been added to the queue, yet is being asked about its contents.

Effectively you have a queue within a queue - it's a mess, because your chosen superclass has its own storage implementation, but you are using your own too, hence the confusion.

If you want to build your own implementation of a queue, implement `Queue`.

Comment: `AbstractQueue` contains no concrete implementation details. It does not have an `offer()` method to call...

Comment: @thkala yes but it has `add()` which needs to be called if you expect `isEmpty()` to work. Remember that the superclass has no visibility whatsoever of your code.

Comment: I repeat, `AbstractQueue` contains *no* implementation details. It has no state at all. It relies on the methods provided by the subclasses for *everything* - for example `add()` calls `offer()`...

Comment: I.e. calling `add()` from `offer()` would lead to a nice `StackOverflowError`. Not to mention that anyone implementing `offer()` using `add()` rather than the other way around deserves anything that happens to them, including (but not limited to) being mauled by a [womp rat](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Womp_rat)...